# How to #define identifier with whitespace

Tags: ios

I was to do something like this: #define '#import "classA.h"' '#import "classB.h"'

I want to override a class that is imported in a library with my custom class. Is there a way to define an identifier that contains a whitespace?

Comment: You should accept an answer or clarify your concerns if they did not resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, because that would be two identifiers then.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick to achieve what you want is to call your header as well "classA.h" but place it in a different directory. Then change the project settings in a way that in the search path for the libraries your directory would be *before* the directory where the original "classA.h" sits.